# Error when updating AppSync API using Amplify CI/CD Pipelines with expired AppSync API KEY: API key not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

We have **AWS Amplify** project with CI/CD enabled and **AppSync** as API enabled for my backend. CI/CD was working fine till the **API_KEY** of **AppSync** app was not expired, now it has been expired and pipelines are failing. I have tried manually updating the **API_KEY** expiration, but the pipeline still fails. There are solutions described to sort out [manually or upgrade Amplify CLI](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2672) version, but it seems I don't have both options in my case.

Do we have any third option?

Below are logs from the build pipeline.

```
2021-09-20T08:26:55.643Z [INFO]: UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS amplify-smsservice-test-115827-apiSmsTest-QXTZ5RMZXWPI AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:26:55 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) User Initiated
2021-09-20T08:27:05.585Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:27:05.588Z [INFO]: UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS          GraphQLSchema                                          AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:01 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS          GraphQLAPIKey                                          AWS::AppSync::ApiKey        Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:01 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_FAILED               GraphQLAPIKey                                          AWS::AppSync::ApiKey        Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:03 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) API key not found: da2-rtqcdxh23bdrneqr746znw4e7i (Service: AWSAppSync; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException; Request ID: 774ee2b5-340d-4e81-8f6d-346a040ee275; Proxy: null)
                                 UPDATE_FAILED               GraphQLSchema                                          AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:04 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) Resource update cancelled
                                 UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS amplify-smsservice-test-115827-apiSmsTest-QXTZ5RMZXWPI AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:05 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) The following resource(s) failed to update: [GraphQLAPIKey, GraphQLSchema].
2021-09-20T08:27:10.509Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:27:10.510Z [INFO]: UPDATE_FAILED               apiSmsTest                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:06 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:331375544915:stack/amplify-smsservice-test-115827-apiSmsTest-QXTZ5RMZXWPI/034ec0e0-0b1e-11ec-a9e0-0affe2668681 was not successfully updated. Currently in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [GraphQLAPIKey, GraphQLSchema].
                                 UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS amplify-smsservice-test-115827 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:06 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) The following resource(s) failed to update: [apiSmsTest].
2021-09-20T08:27:35.515Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:27:35.517Z [INFO]: UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS apiSmsTest AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:27:31 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-09-20T08:28:05.623Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:28:05.624Z [INFO]: UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS GraphQLSchema AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema Mon Sep 20 2021 08:28:01 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_COMPLETE    GraphQLAPIKey AWS::AppSync::ApiKey        Mon Sep 20 2021 08:28:01 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-09-20T08:29:05.663Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:29:05.665Z [INFO]: UPDATE_COMPLETE GraphQLSchema AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema Mon Sep 20 2021 08:29:04 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-09-20T08:29:10.664Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:29:10.665Z [INFO]: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS amplify-smsservice-test-115827-apiSmsTest-QXTZ5RMZXWPI AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:29:06 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-09-20T08:29:30.596Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:29:30.598Z [INFO]: UPDATE_COMPLETE                              apiSmsTest                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:29:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS amplify-smsservice-test-115827 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:29:26 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-09-20T08:29:40.606Z [INFO]: 
2021-09-20T08:29:40.607Z [INFO]: UPDATE_COMPLETE          apiSmsTest                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:29:37 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
                                 UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE amplify-smsservice-test-115827 AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Mon Sep 20 2021 08:29:38 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
2021-09-20T08:29:55.851Z [INFO]: Following resources failed
                                 Resource Name: ilwhx4plcrdbtcnaapvtb6ilpqGraphQLSchema (AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema)
                                 Event Type: update
                                 Reason: Resource update cancelled
                                 URL: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2#/stacks/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-west-2%3A331375544915%3Astack%2Famplify-smsservice-test-115827-apiSmsTest-QXTZ5RMZXWPI%2F034ec0e0-0b1e-11ec-a9e0-0affe2668681/events
2021-09-20T08:29:55.852Z [INFO]: Resource Name: arn:aws:appsync:us-west-2:331375544915:apis/ilwhx4plcrdbtcnaapvtb6ilpq/apikeys/da2-rtqcdxh23bdrneqr746znw4e7i (AWS::AppSync::ApiKey)
                                 Event Type: update
                                 Reason: API key not found: da2-rtqcdxh23bdrneqr746znw4e7i (Service: AWSAppSync; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException; Request ID: 774ee2b5-340d-4e81-8f6d-346a040ee275; Proxy: null)
                                 URL: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2#/stacks/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-west-2%3A331375544915%3Astack%2Famplify-smsservice-test-115827-apiSmsTest-QXTZ5RMZXWPI%2F034ec0e0-0b1e-11ec-a9e0-0affe2668681/events
2021-09-20T08:29:55.852Z [WARNING]: ✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
                                    ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
2021-09-20T08:29:55.860Z [INFO]: [0mResourceNotReady: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete[0m
                                 [0m    at constructor.setError (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/resource_waiter.js:182:47)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.CHECK_ACCEPTORS (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/resource_waiter.js:44:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.callListeners (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.emit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.emit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.transition (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)[0m
                                 [0m    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.callListeners (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.emit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.emit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.transition (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)[0m
                                 [0m    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at Request.callListeners (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)[0m
                                 [0m    at callNextListener (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:336:13)[0m
                                 [0m    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)[0m
                                 [0m    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)[0m
                                 [0m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {[0m
                                 [0m  code: 'ResourceNotReady',[0m
                                 [0m  retryable: false,[0m
                                 [0m  time: 2021-09-20T08:29:50.845Z,[0m
                                 [0m  statusCode: 200,[0m
                                 [0m  retryDelay: 30000[0m
                                 [0m}[0m
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After adding `"CreateAPIKey": 0` to `parametes.json` has resolved my issue.

[Reference](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/config-params/#createapikey)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you forgot to renew the cert or set it to infinity.

You can fix that by updating the nested stack which failed. More info https://blog.arturofm.com/amplify-error/